# Find all complex numbers that satisfies this equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers that satisfies this equation

$(z - 6 + i)^3 = -27.$

I found one of them being $ z = 3 - i $

Comment: We usually write $i$ lower case.

Comment: There are three cube roots of $-27$ so there have to be three solutions to this equation.  Do you know how to find the three cube roots?

Comment: @GregoryGrant i just changed it.

Comment: @GregoryGrant not really

Comment: Hint: If $\zeta=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, then $\zeta^3=-1$ and $(\zeta^2)^3=-1$.

Comment: $-27 =\left(3e^{-i\pi/3}\right)^3 =\left(3e^{i\pi/3}\right)^3 =\left(3e^{i\pi}\right)^3$

Comment: Note that $\zeta^2=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$

Comment: If you know how to do that (using long division), you can now factor the polynomial and get a quadratic equation that you should be able to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z-6+i=\omega$, then your equation change to find the solution of equation $\omega^3=-27$. this equation have the solution's $z_k=3(cos(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{3})+isin(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{3}))$ which $k=0,1,2$. Finally: $z=6-i+z_k$, are all solution's.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Set $z-6+i=3u$ and find all complex numbers $u$ that satisfy $u^3=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$-27=27e^{{\pi}i+2k\pi}$

$\sqrt[3]{27e^{{\pi}i+2k\pi}}=3e^{\frac{1}{3}\pi i+\frac{2}{3}k\pi}=z-6+i$

$z=3e^{\frac{1}{3}\pi i+\frac{2}{3}k\pi}+6-i, \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$